# PersistentVolumeClaim fails to create on Alicloud Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, alibaba-cloud

I am trying to create a Dynamic storage volume on Kubernetes in Ali cloud. 
First I have created a storage class.

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: alicloud-pv-class
provisioner: alicloud/disk
parameters:
  type: cloud_ssd
  regionid: cn-beijing
  zoneid: cn-beijing-b
```

Then, tried creating a persistence volume claim as per below.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: List
items:
- kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
  apiVersion: v1
  metadata:
    name: node-pv
  spec:
    accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
    storageClassName: alicloud-pv-class
    resources:
      requests:
        storage: 64Mi
```

Creation of persistence volume fails with the following error.

> Warning  ProvisioningFailed    0s               alicloud/disk alicloud-disk-controller-68dd8f98cc-z6ql5 5ef317c7-f110-11e8-96de-0a58ac100006  Failed to provision volume with StorageClass "alicloud-pv-class": Aliyun API Error: RequestId: 7B2CA409-3FDE-4BA1-85B9-80F15109824B Status Code: 400 Code: InvalidParameter Message: The specified parameter "Size" is not valid.

I am not sure where this Size parameter is specified. Did anyone come across a similar problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As pointed out in [the docs](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/86612.htm), the minimum size for SSD is `20Gi`, so I'd suggest to change `storage: 64Mi` to `storage: 20Gi` to fix it.